# Clearing the Console from a Laravel Command

Tags: php, laravel, command-line, terminal, lumen

I'm using the Lumen framework for a side project and have created an artisan command that writes a small table to the terminal. What I'm having trouble doing, is clearing the terminal and redrawing the table.

```
public function fire()
{
    $scraper = new scraper();
    $scores = $scraper->scrape();
    $i = 1;
    while($i = 1) {
        $table = new Table($this->getOutput());

        $table->setHeaders(array('', 'Score', 'Status'));
        foreach($scores as $game) {
            $table->addRow([$game->team1['name'], $game->team1['score'], new TableCell($game->gameStatus, array('rowspan' => 2))]);
            $table->addRow([$game->team2['name'], $game->team2['score']]);
            $table->addRow([new TableSeparator(), new TableSeparator(), new TableSeparator()]);
        }
        $table->render();
        sleep(5);
        // Somehow clear the terminal 
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "having trouble"?

Comment: @JoeC "having trouble" as in I'm not sure how to accomplish clearing the console.

Answer (score 7):

A dirty fix would be something like this:

```
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
    system('cls');
} else {
    system('clear');
}
```